# Flex HTML component to bitmap

Tags: apache-flex

I'm creating a HTML Component in Flex, loading a URL and then capturing that element and converting it to a bitmap to try and replicate a sort of automatic screenshot saving process.

However the bitmaps that it is producing do not contain any flash elements from the HTML. Anyone have any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out

I was setting my HTML elements visbility to false when taking the snapshot of that component, it need to be visible when taking the screenshot.

:)